# Writing a loop that chooses random values from columns - Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, random

Created a 2d array with (170,10) shape

```
i = np.array(range(1,1701)).reshape(170,10)
```

Want to write a loop that choses 5 random values **without replacement** from each column (or **n** number of columns) of i and output as below:

```
Group 1: [  7  37 124  41  17]
Group 2: [302 261 257 323 234]
Group 3: [464 486 463 440 474]
```

So far i can pull random values from a single column:

```
print(np.random.choice(i[:,0],5 ,replace=False))
```

How do i put this in a for loop and pull for **n** number of columns with the displayed output (will use .function for that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `shape`, `arange`, and `random.choice`:

```
for c in np.arange(i.shape[1]-1):
    print('Group {}: '.format(str(c+1)) + str(np.random.choice(i[:,c],5,replace=False)))
```

Output:

```
Group 1: [1521  231  671  801  711]
Group 2: [ 612  192 1172 1242 1322]
Group 3: [ 543  213 1453  723  973]
Group 4: [ 404 1334  474  294 1044]
Group 5: [1615 1455 1025 1665 1395]
Group 6: [1116 1336 1086 1626  536]
Group 7: [367 347 887 297 237]
Group 8: [1088 1188 1288   58  608]
Group 9: [1439 1289  869  349 1589]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in xrange(np.shape(i)[-1]):
     print np.random.choice(i[:, n], 5,replace=False)
```

n here is the number of column;
np.shape[-1] would give the total number of columns;
xrange is a generator object that will generate the number of column through the loop.

print statement here is reused from the question, except for the first column, it goes through all columns, with the use of the for loop.

(Thanks rene for pointing me to the right way of doing things.)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!